# Можно ли запустить файл Python с компьютера через бота Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Написал распознаватель лиц на Python, параллельно изучаю написание ботов для Telegram и вот пришла мысль, могу ли я, отправив запрос в телеграме открыть этот файл питона на компьютере ? типа как
`os.system("C:\smt")` или что-то подобное.
Есть какой то способ сделать запуск ?

Comment: Вы можете вынести код с распознаванием лиц в отдельный модуль и импортировать его в телеграмм-боте (только не забудьте выделить отдельный поток распознавателю)

Comment: Идея неплохая, но я бы хотел именно запускать скрипт, например когда комп включен а меня нет в комнате

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-os-python/funktsija-exec-modulja-os/

Comment: А можно ли каким то образом этому файлу передать переменные ? В питоне новичек
Пытаюсь это сделать , не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да вы можете сделать подобное. Для этого вам необходимо создать Telegram бота с помощью одной из популярных библиотек. Скрипт бота должен ожидать определенного сообщения со стороны пользователя, например сообщения : "Запустить скрипт". Также вам необходимо поместить выполняемый скрипт в одну директорию со скриптом бота, назовём этот файл face.py

Для работы с Telegram API необходимо получить токен бота у - https://telegram.me/BotFather

Вот пример реализации с помощью библиотеки Telebot

```
import telebot

token='наш токен'

bot=telebot.Telebot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start_message(message):

  if message.text == 'Запустить скрипт':
     os.system("python face.py")
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Привет ✌️ ")

bot.infinity_poling()
```

После того как пользователь отправит боту сообщение "Запустить скрипт", наш скрипт выполнит команду python face.py - где face.py это файл который нам необходимо запустить